# How to attach fragment while screen orientation change?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, android-videoview, screen-orientation

I am using video-view in fragment. Video-view Fragment work fine but, whenever screen orientation change from landscape to portrait or portrait to landscape. That time video-view fragment destroyed. Is that possible to reattach fragment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use this code inside your manifest

```
<activity
 android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"

</activity>
```

now your activity not destroy after change orientation

Comment: I did it in activity but i  am using fragment for video player,so whenever screen orientation changes then added fragment destroyed.

Comment: @Vasant have you used this code in oncreate of activity  setRetainInstance(true);

Comment: ,Now i put setRetainInstance(true); line in oncreate but it is not working.

Comment: @Vasant sorry you have to put setRetainInstance(true); inside fragment oncreate

Comment: You need to make sure your Activity isn't recreating the fragment. `if (statedInstanceState != null)` you shouldn't be adding the fragment. Also keep in mind that `onCreateView` and `onDestroyView` will be called on your retained fragment on rotation. You should really take a look at the lifecycle and experiment with it, because it's not trivial.

Comment: @Jimeux ,can you give any example or demo-link?

Comment: Take a look at this tutorial http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html